# How to drag and drop an image on delete icon to delete the image?

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop

Hey guys I have just created a sample image view that can be dragged inside the view.

My Question is how to delete the image when it is dragged and placed in the delete icon?

Can anyone help with swift code

Herewith I have attached my sample program code below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {

    var Lastscale : CGFloat = 1.0

    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var deleteIcon: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(recognizer:)))

        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        imgView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
        imgView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    @objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let gview = recognizer.view

        if recognizer.state == .began || recognizer.state == .changed {

            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: gview?.superview)

            gview?.center = CGPoint(x: (gview?.center.x)! + translation.x, y: (gview?.center.y)! + translation.y)

            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gview?.superview)

        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

[image: StoryBoard]

Comment: You'll need to check if image bounds are in the vicinity of your delete icon. Do this in the state == .changed. once the image is at desired area you can manually end the pan gesture and continue with deleting the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's cleaner to use a switch statement to check for recognizer states. Also I think in this case you'd like to set the transform of the layer while the recognizer translation is changing, in this way you retain the initial frame of the view and always can animate back by setting the transform to its identity. Then if the rectangles of the button and image view layer intersect, hide the imageView, else move back. Like this:

```
@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let gview = recognizer.view
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: gview?.superview)

    switch recognizer.state {
    case .began, .changed:
        imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, 0)
        // OR
        // imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y)
    case .ended:
        if deleteIcon.frame.intersects(imgView.layer.frame) {
            animateDelete()
        } else {
            moveBack()
        }
    default:
        moveBack()
    }
}

func animateDelete() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.imgView.alpha = 0
    }) { _ in
        self.imgView.isHidden = true
    }
}

func moveBack() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my latest edit. This line: `imgView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(translation.x, translation.y, 0)`

Comment: I'm glad it helped.